# Does Indy HTTP / HTTPS server work in a Windows Service application?

Tags: https, webserver, indy

Written in RAD Studio 10.4 Sydney C++ Builder, I have a 64-bit Windows application which includes a web-server.  As an interactive Windows application, I have no problems with serving HTTPS.  However, when I try converting this application to being a Windows Service, an exception is thrown when the web-server is initialised:

"Access violation at address 0000000025529F04 in module 'libeay32.dll'. Read of address FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF"

I am using the generated sample web-server application code as the basis of my application, but this requires some changes when implemented in a Windows Service.

I have noticed that the "Application" object is changed when an interactive web-server application is created, so question whether some special approach is required when implementing a Windows Service application.

Any suggestions?

Comment: An Access Violation near address 0 (in this case, `-1`) usually means a `nil` pointer is being accessed.  You need to debug your code to see what code is running at address `0000000025529F04 ` and find the `nil`.

Answer (score 0):

Having significant doubts about the test scenario, I recreated a very much simpler application, and this works - in both 32-bit and 64-bit Windows Services.

Accordingly, it appears that something in my more complicated application is causing this issue.

So, the simple answer to my question is, "No - nothing special is required."